# Как вывести меню и подменю?

Tags: php, html, sql, pdo

Привет всем.

**Задача: вывести меню с подменю, которое соответствует ему(меню).**

*Таблица menu*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*Таблица submenu*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Часть Кода с запросами

```
function get_menu() {
  global $pdo;
  $stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM menu ');
  $menu = $stmt->fetchAll();
  return $menu;
}

function get_submenu() {
  global $pdo;
  $stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM sub_menu ');
  $submenu = $stmt->fetchAll();
  return $submenu;
}
```

HTML

```
<ul class="side-menu">
  <?php foreach ($menu as $item) : ?>
    <li>
     <span><?php echo $item['name']; ?></span>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
         <?php foreach ($submenu as $submenu_item) : ?>
           <?php if($submenu_item['id_menu'] == $item['id']): ?>
            <li><a href=""><?php echo $submenu_item['name']; ?></a></li>
           <?php endif; ?>
         <?php endforeach; ?>
      </ul>
    </li>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Не могу разобраться как сделать проверку: Если есть подменю у меню, то оставлять тег span перед ul и создавать список(2 строчки, к которым это относится)

```
<span><?php echo $item['name']; ?></span>
<ul class="sub-menu"></ul>
```

Если нет подменю у меню - создавать тег a перед ul, но не создавать список через ul.

Comment: На мой взгляд, две таблицы для такой задачи - это лишнее. Даже если без модели `nested sets`, можно было бы просто создать поле а-ля `parent_id`, указывающее на ID родительской категории. Т.е. структуры вашей таблицы `sub_menu` вполне хватило бы.

Comment: Поди самая засада будет при удалении и добавлении.
Интересно очерёдность посмотреть

Answer (score 1):

В вашем примере ошибка в поле для select. Выбирайте `menu_id` и name из `sub_menu`, а не `sub_menu`.

Можно сделать подзапрос. Самое простое:

```php
// PHP

function get_menu() {
  global $pdo;
  $stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM menu ');
  $menu = $stmt->fetchAll();
  return $menu;
}

function get_submenu($menuId) {
  global $pdo;
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT name FROM sub_menu where menu_id = :menu_id');
  $stmt->bindValue('menu_id', $menuId);
  $stmt->execute();
  $submenu = $stmt->fetchAll();
  return $submenu;
}
```

```html
<ul class="side-menu">
  <?php foreach ($menu as $item) : ?>
    <li>
     <span><?php echo $item['name']; ?></span>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
         <?php foreach (get_submenu($item['id']) as $submenu_item) : ?>
            <li><a href=""><?php echo $submenu_item['name']; ?></a></li>
         <?php endforeach; ?>
      </ul>
    </li>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```